# Rails 5.2 - Going From Select To Radio Buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, radio-button

In my ERB view, I have the following two types of select inside a form.

```
<%= f.select :shape, Diamond.shapes.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, v] },{:include_blank => ''},{:class => "form-control", :required => true} %>

<%= select_tag "term[]", options_for_select(Diamond.colors.map { |k,v| [k.upcase, v] }), class: "form-control" %>
```

I am wanting to change it into a radio button or just button and cannot figure out how to code it correctly. The options I have are an enum saved in Diamond.shapes.

Here are the 2 HTML element.

```
<select class="form-control" required="required" name="wholesale[shape]" id="wholesale_shape"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Asscher</option>
<option value="2">Emerald</option>
<option value="3">Heart</option>
<option value="4">Marquise</option>
<option value="5">Oval</option>
<option value="6">Pear</option>
<option value="7">Princess</option>
<option value="8">Radiant</option>
<option value="9">Round</option>
<option value="10">Cushion</option>
</select>

<select name="term[]" id="term_" class="form-control"><option value="14">D</option>
<option value="15">E</option>
<option value="16">F</option>
<option value="17">G</option>
<option value="18">H</option>
<option value="19">I</option>
<option value="20">J</option>
<option value="21">K</option>
<option value="22">L</option>
<option value="23">M</option>
<option value="24">N</option></select>
```

Any ideas? I have been trying radio button collections but havent figured out the correct coding and am not even sure if that is the best way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<% Diamond.colors.keys.each do |color| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :term, color %>
  <%= f.label color.to_sym %>
<% end %>
```